# container pattern with specialized children

Tags: c++, containers, design-patterns

I have several specialized classes. for example

```
class Transition_Matrix : public Transition
{
     SetMatrix(Matrix* pStartMatrix);
};

class Transition_Vector : public Transition
{
     SetVector(Vector* pStartVector);
}

class Transition_Container : public Transition
{

}
```

I would like to do call SetVector() or SetMatrix() on Animate_Container without declaring the functions for each type of object that needs to be set.  For example, I do not want to declare Animate_Container as follows...

```
class Transition_Container : public Transition
{
    SetMatrix(Matrix* pStartMatrix);//loops through all children calling SetMatrix
    SetVector(Vector* pStartVector);//loops through all children calling SetVector
}
```

I don't want Animate_Container to know which children it has.  But I want the convenience of calling these functions on the container so I do not have to search through the children and figure out which functions I should call when "transitioning" a matrix or a vector.

What is the correct pattern that I should use here?

Basically I want to set a matrix or vector on the root container and have it propogate down to each child than may want to use it.

ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) will suffice here. To implement this you declare the member functions as virtual in the base class `Transition`. This will allow you to maintain a list of `Transition` objects in `Transition_Container`, iterate through the list and call the appropriate member function.

```
#include <vector>

class Transition
{
public:
    // default impementation that does nothing
    virtual void SetMatrix(Matrix*) {}  
};

class Transition_Container : public Transition
{
    std::vector<Transition*>    transitions_;

public:
    virtual void SetMatrix(Matrix* pStartMatrix)
    {
        for(std::vector<Transition*>::iterator it = transitions_.begin();
            it != transitions_.end();
            ++it)
        {
            (*it)->SetMatrix(pStartMatrix);
        }
    }
};
```

If you do not want `Transition` to know about the various data types that can be used you can use `boost:any` and `boost:any_cast`. This is very similar to the suggestion above but removes the dependency of `Matrix` and `Vector` from `Transition` and places the responsibility of dealing with different types on the implementation of classes that derive from it. I only recommend doing this if there is some requirement that *absolutely* prevents `Transition` from knowing about the `Matrix` and `Vector` types.

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class Transition
{
public:
    // default impementation that does nothing
    virtual void SetValue(boost::any&) {}  
};


class Transition_Matrix : public Transition
{
    virtual void SetValue(boost::any& value)
    {
        try
        {
            Matrix *matrix = boost::any_cast<Matrix*>(value);

            // do stuff
        }
        catch(const boost::bad_any_cast &)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
};


class Transition_Container : public Transition
{
    std::vector<Transition*>    transitions_;

public:
    template<Arg>
    void SetValueT(Arg* arg)
    {
        boost::any value = arg;
        SetValue(value);
    }

    virtual void SetValue(boost::any& value)
    {
        for(std::vector<Transition*>::iterator it = transitions_.begin();
            it != transitions_.end();
            ++it)
        {
            (*it)->SetValue(value);
        }
    }

};
```

I recommend using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` from Boost or the C++11 Standard Library for maintaining the list of `Transition` objects like so.

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Transition>> transitions_;
```

I did not include this in the above example as I do not know if you are familiar with using this yet. IF you are not I suggest looking into it.

Comment: Yes, this is a good answer and it is the way I have implemented it before.  But, I am wondering if there is a way to do it in such a way that the Transition class does not need to know about Matrix or Vector.

Comment: _Why_ do you not want `Transition` to know about `Matrix` and `Vector`?

Comment: @DannyDiaz I have updated my answer to include an example using `boost::any`